# creating a reactjs carousel

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm looking to create a react carousel that mimics carvana.com on the home page (image attached because they don't always have that homepage up).

I've been doing some research and can't quite figure it out. Any pointers would be very very helpful.

a quick package install would be great, but I've been through about 6 now and they either don't work, or don't have customizable options to get me to that "overflowing off the screen" effect.

More helpful would be a link to a video/class/blog on how to create a carousel from start to finish.

[image]

[image: After clicking the next arrow]

Comment: You can build a carousel using vanilla Javascript inside react. But yes you can keep carousel related data in react state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-carousel-slider, also test here https://codesandbox.io/s/l7qynnp41m.

I have also found several tutorial in youtube to create image carousel with react js like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ax9TW2c2bY

Comment: looks like exactly what i needed. TY